# Building Recommendation engine with Python

Tags: python, apache-mahout, software-recommendation

Which all are the equivalent or advanced libraries in Python for building recommendation systems like [Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/) for  Collaborative Filtering and Content Based Filtering ?

Also is there a way to integrate Mahout with Python?

Comment: There's also the [crab library](http://muricoca.github.io/crab/install.html) however I've never used it so I cannot comment on its performance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a well documented python option for collaborative filtering, but one option is to use [Spark's MLib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html). There is a wrapper that allows you to run it in python ([pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/python-programming-guide.html)) and it is [straightforward](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#spark-standalone-mode) to get it running on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [GraphLab Create](http://dato.com/products/create/)? It's a Python tool for doing many different types of Machine Learning.

General info about their Recommender System can be found [here](https://dato.com/solutions/use-cases/recommendation-engine.html).

A hands-on coding example can be found [here](https://dato.com/learn/gallery/notebooks/basic_recommender_functionalities.html).

Using this product you should be able to create a Recommender System in as few as five lines of code.

One downside, if you're using it for a commercial purpose, you'll need to get a license for the product. Although they do have a free trial period.